# Should a graph of $T^2$ against Mass pass through the origin? Pendulum/spring constant

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, experimental-physics, harmonic-oscillator, spring

[**NOTE to reviewers : Voting to reopen because duplicated question was posted by same user and was closed without answers. This question has been edited in the hope of removing any lack of clarity.**]

I am trying to do a lab in which we are attempting to find the spring constant of a spring.

Different masses are added to a vertical hanging spring, and the time taken for 20 oscillations is recorded for each mass. A straight-line graph of period squared against mass is then plotted and the gradient is calculated.

I am confused about whether the line should pass through the origin. The formula $T^2=4\pi^2 \frac{m}{k}$ tells me that the graph should pass through the origin. However I have to alter two data points to make it pass through the origin. I cannot use a load of zero grammes. Can/should I use (0, 0) as an assumed data point?

Also, how do I know if the motion of the spring is SHM? Does this graph tell me, or do I need to plot a different graph?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should a graph of T^2 against Mass pass through the origin?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/528774/).

Comment: I teach a lab with this exact objective at my university. Though we use the formula $$ T = 2\pi \sqrt{\frac{m + \alpha m_s}{k}}$$ where $m_s$ is the mass of the spring and $\alpha$ is a constant related to the specific spring used. From there you square both sides and you will get the equation of a line when plotting $T^2$ vs $m$

Comment: If your plot of the data does not go through the origin, the correct conclusion is that *your model is incorrect*.  Your data (assuming no mistakes) is, by definition, correct.  It is the consequence of the nature of our world.   It is truth. *Do not change data.*  Your mathematical equation is a model based on various assumptions about the world.   If your model doesn't match the data (I am careful not to say "data does not match the model"), then your model is not correct, although it pretty darn good in some respects.  Answers and comments here have provided improved models.

Comment: What is $m$? Does it include the mass of the spring? "Altering" data points is dishonest and bad science, as is making data up where you have none.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$T=2\pi \sqrt{\frac{m}{k}}$$
Plot of $T^2(m)$ is $y=\frac{4\pi^2}{\sqrt{k}} x$ which is linear line which must cross $(0,0)$ point. If the motion is not harmonic, the line would have large quadratic mean error, or estimate of your line would be rather $y = ax + b$ not $y=ax$.

Oscillator could also become non-harmonic, for example, if your experiment concludes that $k$ has significant dependance from initial position of body $l=l_0$. It would mean that you would get every time new $T$ for same mass $m$ and spring $k$.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the part where you talk about SHM, but now I know that it must pass through the origin. Also does linear mean that it must pass through the origin? (In generall)

Answer (score 3):

The graph should not necessarily pass through the origin.

If you have not confirmed that the period is zero when the load is zero then you should not use $(0, 0)$ as an assumed data point. Neither should you alter recorded data points in order to force the graph to pass through an assumed data point. If you do so you will reduce the accuracy of your measurement of the spring constant $k$ and you will also lose insight into what is happening. Important discoveries can be made when the results of the experiment do not match your expectations.

The formula $T^2=4\pi^2 \frac{m}{k}$ assumes that the spring is ideal and has no mass. If this were true, or if the mass of the spring were very much smaller than the load in all cases then the graph would quite accurately pass through the origin.

In practice springs do have mass. Each part of the spring oscillates when the load oscillates. But not all of the spring oscillates with the same amplitude. The parts near the support hardly move at all while the part nearest the load has the same amplitude as the load.

The effect of the different amplitudes of the spring can be taken into account by using an **effective mass** $\mu$ for the spring. In theory this is equal to approx. $\frac13$ of the actual mass of the spring but again this should not be assumed. $\mu$ contributes to the total inertia which is oscillating and should therefore be added to the load $m$ when you use the formula.

Usually the load will be much greater than that of the spring ($m \gg \mu$), so $\mu$ could be ignored. However for the most accurate work this should not be assumed. In any case, as a matter of principle you should not impose unnecessary assumptions on your experiment.

If you do not know $\mu$ then simply plot $T^2$ against load $m$. This graph will not pass through the origin and you should not use the origin as a data point. The $x$ axis intercept will give you the value of $\mu$ while the slope gives you the value of $k$.

The graph of $T^2$ vs load $m$ is **linear** but if $\mu$ is not negligible compared with loads $m$ then $T^2$ will not be **proportional** to $m$. (But it will be proportional to $m+\mu$.) You do not need the graph to pass through the origin in order to find $k$. All that you need is a constant slope, ie a straight line graph.

---

How can you tell if the motion is SHM?

Assuming that the spring obeys Hooke's Law (extension proportional to load) and the oscillations are kept within this linear limit and there is no energy loss, then the oscillations will be simple harmonic and the graph will be a straight line. However *the converse is not necessarily true.* If the graph is a straight line this *suggests* that the motion is *very likely* to be simple harmonic but the straight-line graph does not prove this beyond dispute.

For example, if there is energy loss then the amplitude of motion will decay but the period will remain constant; the graph of $T^2$ vs $m$ is still linear. Technically this is called **damped harmonic motion** rather than SHM. Alternatively it is possible for two or more factors to conspire to make the graph linear while the motion is not simple harmonic, but this is unlikely. For example, a non-linear spring force and non-linear damping.

The only way to be really sure that motion is SHM is to plot displacement against time and check that this is a sine graph.

Comment: But I am investigating how the change in mass affects the period so I think it should matter?

Comment: Yes that is correct. You should not use the origin as a data point.

Comment: Sorry. I am confused because I believed that all graphs should go through the origin if possible, and I even changed two of my experiment points to do so. So in this case I should disregard the origin? Also I have another question that I hope you can answer if possible. How would my graph of T2 vs mass change if the spring constant was doubled. Thanks

Comment: If you have not measured $T=0$ when $m=0$ then you should not plot this point because it is not a result of your experiment. You should **never** change your experiment points. You might decide to ignore them when you draw a *line of best fit* - eg because they are very far from the line - but you should not erase or change them, because that is dishonest science. Yes in all cases you should ignore the origin if you did not make a measurement there.

Comment: I guess your question about doubling $k$ is asked in your laboratory assignment. This is something you need to work out for yourself. Look at the formula and decide what effect it will have on the slope.

Comment: But what about proportionality?  Wont I lose it if the line does not pass through the origin? Also It is my lab question. I worked out the the K. And i know the equation but i am still not sure of the relation. I think that the line should decrease by half?

Comment: Yes you will lose proportionality. But that does not matter. $k$ is related to the slope. You do not need the graph to pass through the origin in order to find the slope. The graph will have the form $y=ax+b$ instead of $y=ax$. By ignoring the origin (which you did not measure) you make it possible to find both $a$ and $b$. $b$ is related to the effective mass of the spring. If you force the graph to go through the origin you cannot find effective mass of spring and your value for $k$ will not be accurate because you included a false data point.